# ROS2 how do you publish an int array as a message in python? I get vague "raise TypeError()" when i try

Tags: python

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to publish 3 ints as a message but i'm getting this vague error that I'm not sure how to solve this.

This is the relevant bit of my code:

```
self.publisher = self.create_publisher(
    Int32,
    'wheel_settings',
    10)
#test publishing wheel settings
self.publisher.publish([1, 1, 1])
```

Error: "raise TypeError()"

How do I fix this? P

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/377435/ros2-how-do-you-publish-an-int-array-as-a-message-in-python?-i-get-vague-%22raise-typeerror()%22-when-i-try/) by [rydb](https://answers.ros.org/users/53251/rydb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 125 on 2021-04-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

alas, Int32 =/= Int32[]

You'll need to define your publisher to publish arrays (in your case, you can use [Int32MultiArray.msg](https://github.com/ros2/common_interfaces/blob/master/std_msgs/msg/Int32MultiArray.msg)).

In python, (without knowing the contents of `self.create_publisher()`) that could look something like:

```
from std_msgs.msg import Int32MultiArray

...

self.publisher = self.create_publisher(
    Int32MultiArray,
    'wheel_settings',
    10)
...

msg = Int32MultiArray()
msg.data = [1, 1, 1]
pub.publish(msg)
```

---

Originally posted by [shonigmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/69938/shonigmann/) with karma: 1567 on 2021-05-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rydb](https://answers.ros.org/users/53251/rydb/) on 2021-05-04**:
Yep, this fixes it. I wish error handling for this was more specific like "error: expected type x, got type y" or something though.